# Options to load data into Big Query from Google Cloud Storage pro-grammatically in Java?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I have been searching for loading data into Big Query programmatically from Google Cloud Storage. I have done this manually by taking backup of my Google Cloud Storage of one Kind and dumping it into the BigQuery Table and was able to retrive data in android as well. The only problem i am facing is that i want to upload data programmatically into BigQuery Table. 
What are the various methods to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bigquery Java API to load data from cloud storage to Bigquery.

If you need to process the data beforehand, depending on the scale, you can use Google Dataflow to process the data, and then load data or stream data to Bigquery.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery

You can also use Bigquery to directly search files in Cloud storage without loading.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources